# COM Invoke failed: Error 0x800706BE

Tags: com, invoke

All,

I have a COM Server Component (a .Dll) which is developed by someone. When I invoke (using invoke()) a function  in that COM Server, it throws the error  0x800706BE -The remote procedure call failed. Interestingly it throws this error only few times!!. it works fine for the rest of the times!!.

The issue is reported in a windows 2k8 64 bit OS & Win 7 32 bit.

1. Any idea what could be the issue?
2. would it an issue with the COM Server or COM Client ?
3. is there any way by which I can narrow down to know the culprit?

Thanks,
Bytes

Answer (score 1):

ok. It seems I have found out the problem. The COM Server(.dll) was crashing the moment I called Invoke() on that. The problem seems to be in the COM Server.
Hope it will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score -2):

1 : Open an elevated command prompt. To do this, swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search. Or, if you are using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, and then click Search. Type Command Prompt in the Search box, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator. If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or click Allow.

2 : Type the following commands. Press Enter after each command.
Note: It may take several minutes for each command operation to be completed.

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

3 : Close the command prompt, and then run Windows Update again.

Comment: 1. Why would this help? 2. I have edited your answer layout. 3. This refers to e.g. http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26512-dism-fixing-component-store-corruption-windows-8-a.html